# keras - HDF5Matrix causes "Too many open files" error

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, large-data

`HDF5Matrix` Keras function causes `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` error. I have ~1200 `hdf5` files that are used for training a neural network. Limit for a maximum number of open files in my system is 1024. Am I using `HDF5Matrix` function wrong way or is that bug in a function.

Is there any workaround for my situation beside writing own `hdf5` reader?

My code for reading the files:

```
while True:    
    file = .... # choose file to open 
    x1 = HDF5Matrix(file, 'small')
    x2 = HDF5Matrix(file, 'vgg224')
    y = HDF5Matrix(file, 'ab_hist')

    # do something with x1, x2,
```

Comment: Please explain why you have to keep all of these files open, instead of opening, reading & closing them one after another.

Comment: @Anthon I don't want to keep them open, but I think `HDF5Matrix` is doing that itself.

Comment: I wouldn't mask the name of the built-in `file` if I were you, but if you hand in a path to `HDF5Matrix` then indeed you don't have control over the file being closed.

Comment: You could try writing each file using a new thread or process. That way it'd write quicker and you'd be sure that the file is definitely being closed